# Git weird conflict issue?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

```
BASE_API=http://127.0.0.1/transport // <<==== (in red indicating delete)
<<<<<<<
BASE_API=http://127.0.0.1/transport
=======
BASE_API=http://127.0.0.1/transport
>>>>>>>
```

I have a very weird situation above. Basically I'm trying to merge from one branch to another via pull request, and the above case happened, saying there's a merge conflict on the file above.

When I compare manually, the content from both branches are exactly the same and I'm expecting no diff in pull request. Can anyone try to explain what's going on?

Comment: Line ending difference? (LF/CRLF)

Comment: @RomainValeri: I've manually opened up this file in raw version on both branches, and moving cursor trying to highlight to see if it's indeed the case. I dont see any whitespace nor tab?

Answer (score 1):

As comment from @RomainValeri says , maybe you have line difference with some signs.

I usually paste the code from `Git console` in `Notepad++` for example and do:

```
View -> Show Simbol -> Show White Spaces and Tabs / or All Characters..
```

Try to check if there is difference and then usually just delete one of the lines and leave the other so u resolve the conflict